# Different search paths for tclsh

Tags: linux, unix, tcl, sunos

Any one knows how can I invoke the tclsh in the Tcl code due to different paths to tclsh in various platforms (Linux, SUN)?

For example in SUN:

```
#!/usr/bin/sun/tclsh
```

in Linux:

```
#!/usr/bin/linux/tclsh
```

How can I use the same Tcl code and execute it in the above two paths?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`env(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/env) as in

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
```

Also read the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) article.